# Difference Between Data Driven and Keyword Driven Testing?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, data-driven-tests

I searched already to see differences between data and keyword driven testing on Google but I did not find an enough answer for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keywords and data are tools used in automated test scripts.  You use a keyword to represent an action.  A sequence of keywords drive a script.  So you can use the same set of keywords to build a variety of test scripts.  You use data as inputs to your script actions.  Each data set you have in the script, provides a test case.  So the more data sets, the more test cases.  The idea is that these tools help to quickly define numerous test cases and test scripts so that your test coverage is larger.

I wouldn't get too caught up in trying to learn meaning of buzz words.  Just use tools that help you test more and better.

Answer (score 0):

In 8 days, i got something that want to write here:

First thing, kdt is so expensive (for time and people). because of this, almost all automated testing tools uses a hibrit (ddt and kdt) approach. And like Dabowhekk said before, kdt also include test scenarios, actions&events.